# PHOTO import from facebook wall

Tags: facebook

I am working on this site and I want to import photos from facebook group.
https://www.facebook.com/EveryoneLovesaGoldenRetriever/photos
If you visit this link above you will be able to see three albums under heading "Everyone loves a Golden Retriever's Albums" and many photos under heading "Photos of Everyone loves a Golden Retriever" i am able to fetch photos under the albums but not able to sort out how can i fetch other photos that doesnt belong to any albums and comes under heading "Photos of Everyone loves a Golden Retriever"

Thanks you very much in advance
SP

Answer (score 0):

[https://graph.facebook.com/115641638572281/tagged](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=115641638572281%2Ftagged)

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "115641638572281_446639348697240", 
      "from": {
        "name": "Sudhir Puranik", 
        "id": "100000535372598"
      }, 
      "to": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Everyone loves a Golden Retriever", 
            "category": "Small business", 
            "id": "115641638572281"
          }
        ]
      }, 
      "picture": "http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s320x320/541201_446639348697240_100000535372598_1627958_1814759730_n.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=446639348697240&set=o.115641638572281&type=1", 
      "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "http://www.facebook.com/115641638572281/posts/446639348697240"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "http://www.facebook.com/115641638572281/posts/446639348697240"
        }
      ], 
      "type": "photo", 
      "object_id": "446639348697240", 
      "application": {
        "name": "Photos", 
        "id": "2305272732"
      }, 
      "created_time": "2012-05-15T07:43:58+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2012-05-15T07:43:58+0000", 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0
      }
    }, 
    {
      "id": "115641638572281_446033935424448", 
      "from": {
        "name": "Sudhir Puranik", 
        "id": "100000535372598"
      }, 
      "to": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Everyone loves a Golden Retriever", 
            "category": "Small business", 
            "id": "115641638572281"
          }
        ]
      }, 
      "picture": "http://a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s320x320/547601_446033935424448_100000535372598_1626229_2008301193_n.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=446033935424448&set=o.115641638572281&type=1", 
      "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "http://www.facebook.com/115641638572281/posts/446033935424448"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "http://www.facebook.com/115641638572281/posts/446033935424448"
        }
      ], 
      "type": "photo", 
      "object_id": "446033935424448", 
      "application": {
        "name": "Photos", 
        "id": "2305272732"
      }, 
      "created_time": "2012-05-14T12:59:13+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2012-05-15T14:19:48+0000", 
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Barbara Fried", 
            "id": "1336683610"
          }
        ], 
        "count": 1
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "115641638572281_446033935424448_1363348", 
            "from": {
              "name": "Barbara Fried", 
              "id": "1336683610"
            }, 
            "message": "They look like total love dogs!", 
            "created_time": "2012-05-15T14:19:48+0000"
          }
        ], 
        "count": 1
      }
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/115641638572281/tagged?format=json&limit=2&since=1337067838&__previous=1", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/115641638572281/tagged?format=json&limit=2&until=1337000352"
  }
}
```